# Updating Model from Viewmodel will not commit

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I had this method in my controller working.  However, if the user wanted to go back the way I was going back would not refresh the page.  On a previous thread on here it was recommended I switch my strongly typed view from using the `Ticket` model to using a new `TicketView` model.  That fixed the issue with hitting the link to go back not refreshing.  Although, unfortunately now I cannot edit my tickets.  Here is the my controller code that I use to edit the ticket:

```
public ActionResult EditTechTicket(TicketView ticketReturn, string returnUrl)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ticket.TicketId = ticket.TicketId;
    ticket.CategoryId = ticketReturn.CategoryId;
    if (ticketReturn.TicketStatusId == new Guid("553F4C93-4A72-44BD-A9CE-FAB4F87D4E08") & ticket.CloseDate == null)
    {
        ticket.CloseDate = DateTime.Now;
    }
    else if (ticketReturn.TicketStatusId != new Guid("553F4C93-4A72-44BD-A9CE-FAB4F87D4E08") & ticket.CloseDate != null)
    {
        ticket.CloseDate = null;
    }
    else
    {
        ticket.CloseDate = ticketReturn.CloseDate;
    }

    ticket.OpenDate = ticketReturn.OpenDate;
    ticket.OpenUserId = ticketReturn.OpenUserId;
    ticket.TechnicianId = ticketReturn.TechnicianId;
    ticket.TicketNumber = ticketReturn.TicketNumber;
    ticket.TicketStatusId = ticketReturn.TicketStatusId;

    tickets.Update(ticket);
    tickets.Commit();

        return RedirectToAction("EditTechTicket", new { id = ticketReturn.TicketId, returnUrl = returnUrl });
 }
```

The code crashes on the `tickets.Commit();` statement.  What am I missing?

This is what the crash says:

> The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

I already checked both the model and viewmodel for Open Date are non-nullable and both the model and viewmodel for closedate are nullable.

Comment: What ORM are you using?  Is .Commit and .Update methods on the ORM or on a repository?

Comment: @AaronLS Repository.  It worked prior to switching it to the viewmodel.  Do you need to see the repository code?

Comment: First off, you are assigning stuff to itself repeatedly. Look at your code again and fix all the spots where `ticket` should be `ticketReturn`.

Comment: You should run a sql profiler to see what sql code is being generated by your ORM if your 'tickets.commit();' is not generating an error. Also, like br4d said, you have a lot of lines that simply don't make sense. Like 'ticket.TicketId = ticket.TicketId;' and 'ticket.OpenDate = ticket.OpenDate;'.

Comment: @br4d sorry that was me testing something and forgot to change the code back.  Although I was wrong it does crash on the commit code.

Comment: When it "crashes" then there is an exception full of essential information. Post it.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I added the exception to the original post

Comment: Have you looked in the debugger where the crash occurs for the date that isn't getting its value set? It will show as 01/01/0001 which the default value for a DateTime. Make sure it is getting set correctly. Probably the CloseDate

Comment: @br4d, no that is currently void like it is supposed to be.  Oddly it is the OpenDate coming through like that.

Comment: Make sure you are putting OpenDate into either a TextBoxFor or HiddenFor in the view that is posting to this action method

Comment: The OpenDate cannot change so I commented it out just now and it commits but the view still shows the old data (even though if I look in the database the data is correctly updated)

Comment: Then put opendate into a hidden field in the view so you don't lose it between requests

Comment: @br4d, I already show it on the page, in a non-editable field.  Do I still need to put in a hidden field?

Comment: What do you mean by 'non-editable' ?  A `label`?  or input that's `disabled`?  Disabled inputs do not get posted / modelbound.

Comment: @br4d I would assume `ticket` is the entity model and `tickerReturn` which is declared as `TicketView` is the view model, so the assignments are typical of this kind of pattern, but it certainly is very vague because we can't see where `ticket` is declared.  Usually the new entity would be declared in the action method.

Answer (score 4):

You already have the answer from your exception

> The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type
>   resulted in an out-of-range value.

Any date stored to sql server must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999. It does not matter if it is null DateTime or not. if you are passing back a value of a DateTime.Min() then it will error out every time.

As said in the comments if you have a DateTime value that does not change then you can simply make a hidden field on your form or **readonly** field that post back the correct data. Note that disabled fields DO NOT post back and maybe part of your problem.

You should update this line to use the ticketReturn viewmodel passed in.

```
ticket.TicketId = ticketReturn.TicketId;
```